# How to match comma separated values from a column in Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, hql

I have a VARCHAR2 column which stores data like '1,2,3'

I need to fetch values from HQL where I would be passing list of string parameter like ['1','2','3'].

I need to fetch records where there's a partial or full match.

Solution approach:
I'm thinking of building a native query through java and build a suitable regex dynamically. We can append the digits in the regex dynamically to use in the query. We can then use 'regexp_like' in the query to retrieve results. Regex can be something like ^1$,^2$,^3*.

But I'm not able to get the correct regex for this.

Comment: so you need records  that match 1% or 1,2% or 1,2,3% ? Similarly for 2 and 3?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Yes, it should search for those combinations and retrieve results. I could use a bunch of OR conditions but that won't be very efficient.

Comment: yes, the conditions would be more like permutations.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo Yes, that's correct. Hence, I was seeing if this can be solved using regex.

Comment: this will bring everything matches 123 digits `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  col_name REGEXP   '[1-3]' ` but again you have to check if the returned results have `,` between the digits or not as this will return 42 as well which is a false positive.

Comment: maybe fetch these results and write a method to split with comma and then match if the array matches 1,2 or 3. The above query will filter a good portion of results and then application layer will handle the data or you can write a SP to do the job.